# when ever a if condition satisfied then we need to pass ctrl+c to stop current item and start the next one in shell script?

Tags: shell, batch-file

Real scenario which I am facing is below,

1. I am having a bat file to monitor the last updated file based on last modified time and it will tell the user if the file not getting updated with in last 1 min.

   2.But my scenario is ,we are using the last modified bat file to monitor the log file update. If the log file not updated in the last 1 min then the script has to send Ctrl + C thru script itself to stop the current test.
2. Currently when the file not updated with in 1 min then manually we will do Ctrl+C and then the system will ask us like need to  exit ? we will say no then it will continue the next test suite.

   Currently I am having script to monitor the log file update based on last modified date and time. But i need to automate the steps which i provided in 3.

   To check last modified file pls refer below:

copy the below and save it as .bat file with  name as checkfolder.

```
@echo off
:: Wmic removes regional differences
:: XP Pro can have some filename errors due to the short filename bug

setlocal
:: set the number of minutes in the following line
set minutes=1

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "stamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"
call :DateToMinutes %stamp% NowMins

set "name="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir * /a-d /b /od ^|find /v /i "%~nx0"') do set "name=%%a"
if defined name call :CheckMins "%name%"
if %MinsOld% gtr %minutes% echo Folder hasn't been modified in %minutes% minutes & pause

goto :EOF

:CheckMins
set "filestamp="
set "filemins="
set "MinsOld="
set "YY=" & set "YYYY=" & set "MM=" & set "DD="
set "HH=" & set "Min=" & set "Sec=" & set "dt="
set "file=%~sf1"
:: can use CreationDate instead of lastmodified
WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="%file:\=\\%" get lastmodified | find "." >test.txt
for /f %%a in (rh5.log) do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "filestamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"
del test.txt 2>nul
if not defined yyyy goto :EOF

call :DateToMinutes %filestamp% FileMins
set /a MinsOld=%NowMins%-%FileMins%
goto :EOF

:DateToMinutes
setlocal
set yy=%1&set mm=%2&set dd=%3&set hh=%4&set nn=%5
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
set /a j=j/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2472633
if 1%hh% LSS 20 set hh=0%hh%
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {p} if "%hh%" NEQ "12" set hh=1%hh%&set/a hh-=88
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {a} if "%hh%" EQU "12" set hh=00
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} GEQ {a} set nn=%nn:~0,2%
set /a hh=100%hh%%%100,nn=100%nn%%%100,j=j*1440+hh*60+nn
endlocal&set %6=%j%&goto :EOF
```

copy the below and save it as filechecker .bat

```
@echo off
:loop
call "checkfolder.bat"
timeout /t 60 /nobreak
goto :loop
```

Then create txt file with the name test.txt. have all the three in same folder and click on checkfolder.bat to verify.

My question is,

Here i got the response as file not modified after that i need to pass ctrl+c thru script  and the i have to pass the value as 'n' and hit enter.

if( file not updated)
   ctrl+c and then provide n as input to start the next suite

Kindly help me out with this..

Comment: "batch", not "bash", is it?

Comment: I also thought it was linux...

Comment: yes..it is batch file...

Comment: see [programmatically "press" Ctrl-C / Exit batch inside CALL](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5859#p36430)

Answer (score 0):

see [programmatically "press" Ctrl-C / Exit batch inside CALL](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5859#p36430)

Also, you may use a batch and vb hybrid to send keys to whatever window you want... In this sample, keys are sent to current `cmd` window. You may need to adjust timings to avoid something being echoed between `Ctrl+C` and `s`

```
@echo off

for /L %%a in (1,1,100) do (
  echo(Test waiting for Ctrl+C, loop %%a
  ping 1.1.1.1 -w 500 -n 1 > NUL
  if %%a equ 6 call :sendCTRLC_WAIT
)

echo(This is never reached.
exit/B


rem wait for a second until ctrl-c is sent to this cmd session
:sendCTRLC_WAIT
SetLocal
set "_file1_=%TEMP%\after.vbs"
set "_file2_=%TEMP%\ctrlc.vbs"
>"%_file1_%" (
  echo(wScript.Sleep 1300
  echo(set oWS = CreateObject("wScript.Shell"^)
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "s"
  echo(wScript.Sleep 50
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
)
>"%_file2_%" (
  echo(wScript.Sleep 1000  
  echo(set oWS = CreateObject("wScript.Shell"^)
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "^{c}"
)
start /B cmd /C ""%_file1_%"" & rem del /F /Q "%_file1_%" 2>NUL"
start /B cmd /C ""%_file2_%"" & rem del /F /Q "%_file2_%" 2>NUL"
exit/B 0


:sendCTRLC_TESTED
SetLocal
set "_file1_=%TEMP%\after.vbs"
set "_file2_=%TEMP%\ctrlc.vbs"
>"%_file1_%" (
  echo(wScript.Sleep 300
  echo(set oWS = CreateObject("wScript.Shell"^)
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "s"
  echo(wScript.Sleep 50
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
)
>"%_file2_%" (
  echo(set oWS = CreateObject("wScript.Shell"^)
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "^{c}"
)
start /B cmd /C ""%_file1_%"" & rem del /F /Q "%_file1_%" 2>NUL"
start /B cmd /C ""%_file2_%"" & rem del /F /Q "%_file2_%" 2>NUL"
exit/B 0
```