# How to have the correct execution from a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

This is my bat script:

```
@echo off
cls

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (Keys.txt) do (
  RoundKey.exe "%%a"


)
```

The file Keys.txt contains in each line a key that I need to change executing the RooundKey.exe program. This program take in parameter just one  key. I have at total `10000 keys`, so it is very hard to change them one by one. The output from the RoundKey.exe program while executing it in the  command line is:

This is the command line:

```
RoundKey.exe  "E0 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F"
```

This is the output:

```
00: E0 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
01: 36 AA 74 FD 32 AF 72 FA 3A A6 78 F1 36 AB 76 FE
02: 56 92 CF F8 64 3D BD 02 5E 9B C5 F3 68 30 B3 0D
03: 56 FF 18 BD 32 C2 A5 BF 6C 59 60 4C 04 69 D3 41
04: A7 99 9B 4F 95 5B 3E F0 F9 02 5E BC FD 6B 8D FD
05: C8 C4 CF 1B 5D 9F F1 EB A4 9D AF 57 59 F6 22 AA
06: AA 57 63 D0 F7 C8 92 3B 53 55 3D 6C 0A A3 1F C6
07: E0 97 D7 B7 17 5F 45 8C 44 0A 78 E0 4E A9 67 26
08: B3 12 20 98 A4 4D 65 14 E0 47 1D F4 AE EE 7A D2
09: 80 C8 95 7C 24 85 F0 68 C4 C2 ED 9C 6A 2C 97 4E
10: C7 40 BA 7E E3 C5 4A 16 27 07 A7 8A 4D 2B 30 C4
```

I put this batch script to help in doing that, Let's suppose that I have in my keys.txt file:

```
e0 01 02 21 03 05 06 67 08 88 0a 0b ea 0d ac 08
00 45 22 03 64 05 56 07 98 ea 1a 56 1f 1d 78 1a
50 01 02 53 04 05 78 08 10 4c 0a 89 cb 0d a6 cb
......
```

so when I execute my bash script, I get  just the result of the first key, then it is sleeped. I put CTRL+C IT two times, I got as a result the second key, the same for the third key:

```
   00: E0 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
01: 36 AA 74 FD 32 AF 72 FA 3A A6 78 F1 36 AB 76 FE
02: 56 92 CF F8 64 3D BD 02 5E 9B C5 F3 68 30 B3 0D
03: 56 FF 18 BD 32 C2 A5 BF 6C 59 60 4C 04 69 D3 41
04: A7 99 9B 4F 95 5B 3E F0 F9 02 5E BC FD 6B 8D FD
05: C8 C4 CF 1B 5D 9F F1 EB A4 9D AF 57 59 F6 22 AA
06: AA 57 63 D0 F7 C8 92 3B 53 55 3D 6C 0A A3 1F C6
07: E0 97 D7 B7 17 5F 45 8C 44 0A 78 E0 4E A9 67 26
08: B3 12 20 98 A4 4D 65 14 E0 47 1D F4 AE EE 7A D2
09: 80 C8 95 7C 24 85 F0 68 C4 C2 ED 9C 6A 2C 97 4E
10: C7 40 BA 7E E3 C5 4A 16 27 07 A7 8A 4D 2B 30 C4
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
^C00: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
01: D6 AA 74 FD D2 AF 72 FA DA A6 78 F1 D6 AB 76 FE
02: B6 92 CF 0B 64 3D BD F1 BE 9B C5 00 68 30 B3 FE
03: B6 FF 74 4E D2 C2 C9 BF 6C 59 0C BF 04 69 BF 41
04: 47 F7 F7 BC 95 35 3E 03 F9 6C 32 BC FD 05 8D FD
05: 3C AA A3 E8 A9 9F 9D EB 50 F3 AF 57 AD F6 22 AA
06: 5E 39 0F 7D F7 A6 92 96 A7 55 3D C1 0A A3 1F 6B
07: 14 F9 70 1A E3 5F E2 8C 44 0A DF 4D 4E A9 C0 26
08: 47 43 87 35 A4 1C 65 B9 E0 16 BA F4 AE BF 7A D2
09: 54 99 32 D1 F0 85 57 68 10 93 ED 9C BE 2C 97 4E
10: 13 11 1D 7F E3 94 4A 17 F3 07 A7 8B 4D 2B 30 C5
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
^C00: 50 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
01: 86 AA 74 FD 82 AF 72 FA 8A A6 78 F1 86 AB 76 FE
02: E6 92 CF B9 64 3D BD 43 EE 9B C5 B2 68 30 B3 4C
03: E6 FF E6 FC 82 C2 5B BF 6C 59 9E 0D 04 69 2D 41
04: 17 27 65 0E 95 E5 3E B1 F9 BC A0 BC FD D5 8D FD
05: 04 7A 31 5A 91 9F 0F EB 68 23 AF 57 95 F6 22 AA
06: 66 E9 9D 70 F7 76 92 9B 9F 55 3D CC 0A A3 1F 66
07: 2C 29 AE 17 DB 5F 3C 8C 44 0A 01 40 4E A9 1E 26
08: 7F 5B 59 38 A4 04 65 B4 E0 0E 64 F4 AE A7 7A D2
09: 38 81 EC DC 9C 85 89 68 7C 8B ED 9C D2 2C 97 4E
10: 7F 09 C3 69 E3 8C 4A 01 9F 07 A7 9D 4D 2B 30 D3
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
^C'n' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So How could I please resolve this problem?

Comment: seem that `roundkey.exe` expects some user input. need further details to provide a useful workaround. how is `roundkey` working, what is the output expected, how we may tell our crystal ball _please, what's going on?_ BTW, if you run the program from command line, which output does it give?

Comment: @elzooilogico  Could you please see the edited program?

Comment: another one `echo n|roundkey.exe %%a`

Comment: @elzooilogico  echo n | RoundKey.exe "%%a"  gives me the same results

Comment: one more `cmd /c "readkey.exe %%a"`

Comment: @elzooilogico  same results for cmd /c RoundKey.exe "%%a"

Comment: I need to have CTRL + C after each iteration.

Comment: no problem, but not in front of computer. a csript hybryd with`sendkeys` will do the trick. I'll send a link when I can

Comment: @elzooilogico  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784739/when-ever-a-if-condition-satisfied-then-we-need-to-pass-ctrlc-to-stop-current-i/43819871#43819871) this is what I can do this time. here we are midnight having fun ;-)

Comment: @elzooilogico thank you for your help

Comment: @elzooilogico: `midnight` + `being here` = `fun` ... `<like>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, the default "Exit" of `RoundKey` is a `Ctrl-C` (no other key works).

But you can `start /b` the program and forcefully kill it after a short wait time:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (keys.txt) do (
  echo ----------
  start /b "" RoundKey.exe "%%a"
  timeout -t 1 >nul
  taskkill /f /im:RoundKey.exe >nul
)
```

Not sure, which output you need. If you need the last line(s) only:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (keys.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('
       start /b "" roundkey.exe "%%a" ^& timeout 1 ^>nul ^& taskkill /f /im:RoundKey.exe ^>nul
     ') do set "key=%%b"
  echo !key! (Input was: %%a)
)
```

Comment: the only thing I dislike more than forcefully killing a tool is a tool, that forces me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you may try the solution from *Stephan*

another workaround is use `cscript` to send desired key to the process

```
@echo off
cls

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (Keys.txt) do (
  call :sendCTRLC
  RoundKey.exe "%%a"
)

exit/B

rem adjust sleep time to fit your needs 
:sendCTRLC
SetLocal
>"ctrlc.vbs" (
  echo(wScript.Sleep 1500 
  echo(set oWS = CreateObject("wScript.Shell"^)
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "^{c}"
)
start /B cmd /C ""ctrlc.vbs" & del "ctrlc.vbs" 2>NUL"
EndLocal
exit/B 0
```

As `Stephan` suggested, if more keystrokes are needed, you may rewrite code as

```
:sendCTRLC
SetLocal
>"after.vbs" (
  echo(wScript.Sleep 1800
  echo(set oWS = CreateObject("wScript.Shell"^)
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "n"
  echo(wScript.Sleep 50
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
)
>"ctrlc.vbs" (
  echo(wScript.Sleep 1500 
  echo(set oWS = CreateObject("wScript.Shell"^)
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "^{c}"
)
start /B cmd /C ""after.vbs" & del "after.vbs" 2>NUL"
start /B cmd /C ""ctrlc.vbs" & del "ctrlc.vbs" 2>NUL"
EndLocal    
exit/B 0
```

Comment: don't think, this will work, because `call` is never reached (RoundKey is waiting for Ctrl-C). Maybe if you start the vbs *before*  RoundKey and give it another `N{Enter} to answer `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`

Comment: give it an additional `N{Enter}` and it's nearly fine (aside from the ugly "Terminate" message)

Comment: @Stephan, yes, yes. I need more coffee in the mornings, ;-)

Comment: [c(_)](http://isolotti.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/sumptuous-design-huge-coffee-mug-manificent-decoration-78-best-images-about-mug-me-on-pinterest.jpg)