# How to simulate ctrl-c in Windows cmd line?

Tags: python, ssh, cmd, process, paramiko

I want to interrupt (I do not want to kill it) a process through the use of the terminal. Currently, the only way I am able to stop the process is by physically tapping Ctrl+C. However, for the sake of the program I am building, I do not want to have to tap Ctrl+C. Is there a way to type a command that does the same thing as tapping Ctrl+C on the Windows command line? I need to be able to do this for my program I am using paramiko to send cmd commands, but I can't use ctrl+c in paramiko.

i.e. cmd ctrl-c interrupt_this_program

Comment: raise KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: @rosh typing that in cmd line doesn't work since raise is not a recognizable command. what do I do?

Comment: To send a console control event, you first have to attach to the same console as the target process via `AttachConsole(target_pid)`. This is easiest to do from a non-console (GUI) app since you can only attach to one console at a time. Then call `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` to send a `CTRL_C_EVENT`. This targets a process group, like Unix `killpg`, so it's simplest to just broadcast the event to all attached processes by sending to group 0. Of course that includes your own process, so make sure to ignore Ctrl+C events in your process via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, TRUE)`.

Comment: recently someone had a similar problem. Maybe [the same method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44196110/2152082) works for you.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line use command `taskkill`. Get help on this command by running in a command prompt window `taskkill /?`.

`taskkill` **without** usage of option `/F` sends to the specified process the event message to **terminate**, i.e. the [WM_CLOSE message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617.aspx). If the application is coded to process this general Windows message, it should terminate itself as soon as possible with saving all not yet saved data.

`taskkill` **with** usage of option `/F` really **kills** the specified process (application) by the operating system without giving the running application the chance to terminate itself with saving all data. So option `/F` should be used only if the application does not respond on the terminate message because of not being coded to break its execution on receiving that message from operating system.

Comment: Presumably the target process has a Ctrl+C handler that does a graceful exit, but it's possible to extend this to also support the `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`. When the console is closed via `WM_CLOSE`, it sends this event to each attached process and gives it 5 seconds to handle the event and exit gracefully,  after which it calls `TerminateProcess` to kill it.

Comment: An important caveat here is that taskkill will only send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the console window when the target process is the controlling process for the console, which is typically the process that created the console. Otherwise it will fail and report that using `/F` is required. So you have to target the controlling process, and this will terminate every process that's attached to the console.

Comment: A console application also has the option to create a hidden window to be able to directly receive a `WM_CLOSE` message, but it's rare for a console app to own a window. They typically only work with standard I/O provided by the console, pipes, and files.