# How to exit a process gracefully from windows. Preferrably via GITBASH

Tags: windows, git-bash, sigterm, shutdown-hook, graceful-shutdown

I am in windows and have a java program with shutdownhook.
When i run it as a jar in a cmd and press ctr c (interrupt signal), the shutdown gets invoked correctly.
On the other hand when i try to kill this command gracefully using `kill -15 processId` or `kill -TERM processId`, this shutdownhook is not invoked, but the application is terminated. (Used gitbash in windows OS for this.)

On further searching read that the `kill -15 processId` and `kill -TERM processId` might behave differently in windows.

Is there any way we can invoke `kill -15 processId` or `kill -TERM processId` or any other command to close a process gracefully based on processId from windows, if possible via gitbash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318762/how-to-simulate-ctrl-c-in-windows-cmd-line